# Best way to store a csv database in memory?

Tags: python

I have a text file (CSV) which acts as a database for my application formatted as follows:

```
ID(INT),NAME(STRING),AGE(INT)
1,John,23
2,Paul,34
3,Jack,12
```

Before you ask, I cannot get away from a CSV text file (imposed) but I can remove/change the first row (header) into another format or into another file all together (I added it to keep track of the schema).

When I start my application I want to read-in all the data in-memory so I can then query it and change it and stuff. I need to extra:

```
- Schema (column names and types)
- Data
```

I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to store this in memory using Python (very new to the language and its constructs) - any suggestions/recommendations?
Thanks,

Comment: Maybe as a pandas data frame?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian was a great idea but it looks like I need to code something myself using only native stuff (can't import anything not already in Python3.0) - any suggestions?

Comment: If you have to stay in the native library, then what about looking up the standard library, https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian now that is awesome!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) you can query it like it was an SQL table, and read it directly from CSV and write it back out as well. I think that this is the best option for you. It's very fast and performant, and builds on solid, proven technologies.

Comment: Great idea - not sure I will be allowed to use it (this is for a project - and it seems to powerful - prof wants me to hand-write this out) but it does exactly give me what I asked for it the question :)

Comment: Understood. In that case, I'd just use the CSV module. You can come up with a few different ways to query it. If there is a column that can be used as an index, you can use that column as a key to a `dict`, and store the rest of the data from the row as a `list`as the value for that key.